# I want to write a app for mac but I have no programming experience, is objective c suitable to start with as a first language?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I know specifically what I want to build. The first task I will embark on is building a programme that will shutdown my mac at a specific time without a prompt. I know it can be done via system preferences, but the option of cancelling the shutdown defeats the purpose.

With that in mind, is objective C recommended as a first language to learn and build the programme? Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic here, peruse the material in the help centre to understand what questions are welcome and what are not.

Comment: Your question is probably strictly off topic, but in the interest of helping a future programmer, simple tasks like this are better handled with scripting. There are many tutorials on this. If you want to learn programming, many universities teach Python as a first language. Objective C, while a powerful tool is not a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

A program will usually have a user interface and otherwise interact with the platform in many ways. To do that, it's not enough to learn the programming language—you also have to know and understand many concepts of the operating system.

Apple calls the union of Objective-C and the provided frameworks "Cocoa", because programming for the Mac is not only about the syntax and semantics of Objective-C.

For your purpose you have to access various system functionalities. Cocoa and Objective-C, while imposing a steep learning curve at the beginning, are well suited for this task, as they form the most natural way to interact with many parts of the OS.

That said, if your purpose is mainly creating this single app, then there are easier ways to get the job done. Learning Cocoa on the other hand is advisable only if you really want to dive into programming.